# How can I get Pandoc to preserve my reference links?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm using the Pandoc-format extension in Visual Studio Code to format my markdown documents.

I write my reference links in a similar style to Stack Overflow, like this:

```
This is a test file, created by Tim at [Tigra Astronomy][tigra].

This is another line.

[tigra]: http://tigra-astronomy.com "Tigra home page"
```

Pandoc really mangles these references. I've tried various combinations of options and command-line experiments, such as:

```bsh
pandoc .\input.md --from markdown --to markdown-shortcut_reference_links --reference-links --reference-location=document
```

that command actually produces this output:

> This is a test file, created by Tim at [Tigra Astronomy][].
>
> This is another line.
>
> [Tigra Astronomy]: http://tigra-astronomy.com "Tigra home page"

...which is pretty close but still not quite there. So is there a way I can persuade Pandoc to just keep my references 'as written'?

Comment: AFAIK this is a current limitation of pandoc. It just wasn't designed as a prettifier...

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way I can persuade Pandoc to just keep my references 'as written'?

In short **no**, as Pandoc does not retain that information.

With the command `pandoc --from markdown --to native` you can have Pandoc output the [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://pandoc.org/using-the-pandoc-api.html#walking-the-ast) (AST), which is Pandoc's internal native representation of the document. For your sample document, the AST looks like this (see also the [online demo](https://pandoc.org/try/?text=This+is+a+test+file%2C+created+by+Tim+at+%5BTigra+Astronomy%5D%5Btigra%5D.%0A%0AThis+is+another+line.%0A%0A%5Btigra%5D%3A+http%3A%2F%2Ftigra-astronomy.com+%22Tigra+home+page%22&from=markdown&to=native)):

```
[Para [Str "This",Space,Str "is",Space,Str "a",Space,Str "test",Space,Str "file,",Space,Str "created",Space,Str "by",Space,Str "Tim",Space,Str "at",Space,Link ("",[],[]) [Str "Tigra",Space,Str "Astronomy"] ("http://tigra-astronomy.com","Tigra home page"),Str "."]
,Para [Str "This",Space,Str "is",Space,Str "another",Space,Str "line."]]
```

As you can see, the link does not retain the "name" you assigned it. Therefore, when Pandoc converts the AST back into Markdown, it cannot use your "name" as it is not available. Initially I had thought that perhaps you could use a [filter](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) or [custom writer](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-writers) to include your reference name, but that won't work either as the name is simply not available.

In the end, this should not be surprising. Pandoc does not promise to retain all meta-data included in documents. In fact, the documentation [warns](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#description):

> Because pandoc’s intermediate representation of a document is less
>   expressive than many of the formats it converts between, one should
>   not expect perfect conversions between every format and every other.
>   Pandoc attempts to preserve the structural elements of a document, but
>   not formatting details such as margin size. And some document
>   elements, such as complex tables, may not fit into pandoc’s simple
>   document model. While conversions from pandoc’s Markdown to all
>   formats aspire to be perfect, conversions from formats more expressive
>   than pandoc’s Markdown can be expected to be lossy.

Of course, the reference name is a Markdown specific feature. However, Markdown supports representing links in multiple ways and maintaining reference names is not necessary to maintain a valid Markdown document. Therefore reference names are one of the things that Pandoc looses.

But why does Pandoc need to run through the AST if it is just outputing the same format. Because that is how it is architected.  See the [API documentation](https://pandoc.org/using-the-pandoc-api.html#pandocs-architecture) for more information on that.

Comment: This is a very nice explanation.  Aside from this, I think it would at least be possible to have numbered reference links throughout the document.  This requires writing a custom filter in LUA.

Answer (score 0):

There is a native way to keep the link title in Pandoc markdown like this : [I'm an inline-style link with title](https://www.noproblemo.ca)

```
[I'm an inline-style link with title](https://www.noproblemo.ca "No Problemo")
```

As you can see, the title is in parenthesis separates by a space from URL in quote mark.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been a while this question's been asked but just in case someone is still looking for an answer. Markdown files have already options to create links, you can find the details and **pandoc** command that I use below. The pandoc version that I use is `2.19.2` with **pdflatex** engine.

I did use double square brackets to imply it's a reference.

```
1. [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:About)
2. [[Google]](https://www.google.com/)
```

Pandoc command

```
pandoc --variable classoption=twocolumn --variable papersize=a4paper YOUR_FILE.md -o YOUR_FILE.pdf --pdf-engine=/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```

or

```
pandoc --variable classoption=twocolumn --variable papersize=a4paper --wrap=preserve --reference-links YOUR_FILE.md -o YOUR_FILE.pdf --pdf-engine=/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```